# Can't rsync to a destination in /etc

Tags: rsync

After an upgrade from Debian 10 to 11 an rsync job with some destination in /etc does not work anymore.

On the server (destination) side I have this:

```
uid = root
gid = root

hosts allow = mysender

[mymodule]
  # NOGO
  path = /etc/tmp

  # GO
  # path = /root/tmp

  comment = Just for testing
  read only = false
```

On the client side (source) I enter this command:

```
rsync -a /etc/temp/test myserver::mymodule
```

Which makes rsync fail with this message:

```
rsync: [generator] recv_generator: mkdir "/test" (in mymodule) failed: Read-only file system (30)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Configuring the server to use a path outside of /etc (for example /root/tmp) does work as expected.

The root file system (which also contains the /etc directory) is **not** mounted read-only of course and it is clean. Why does rsyncd consider /etc being part of a read-only file system then?

Comment: You do have the `/etc/tmp` target directory? It's an unusual path

Comment: Yes. I know it is unusual but it is just for testing.

Comment: Are you running SELinux

Comment: No SELinux, neither on server nor on client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rsync Version 3.2.0-1 introduced an enhancement called "ProtectSystem" that prevents, among other things, write access to `/etc` (see https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS).
This can be overridden by creating a file `/etc/systemd/system/rsync.service.d/override.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
ProtectSystem=off
```

Hope, that helps so long after your initial post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves my problem. I should have read the comments in /lib/systemd/system/rsync.service.